# Type mismatch error in For Each loop looping through each control

Tags: vba, ms-access

I set up a userform that checks if checkbox control is checked and if so add the tag's value to a variable. Each control has a unique number in its tag.

```
Dim ctl As Control
Dim sum As Long

For Each ctl In Userform1.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acCheckBox Then
        If ctl.Value = True Then sum = sum + ctl.Tag
    End If
Next
Me.TextBox7 = sum
```

However, when the code gets to the for each statement, a type mismatch error is thrown and ctl = Nothing. I've added a break to see if this error is happening on the first iteration and that seems to be the case. Thoughts? This was supposed to be a simple little tool to help with another project...

Comment: I think you need to ensure `Userform1` is loaded before you can loop through it's controls. Before you do that though, make sure `Userform1` is actually the name of a userform in your database. I'd also rename 'sum' to something other than 'sum', say like 'tagSum'?

Comment: I probably should have specified. This code is run when a button on the form is clicked. So the form is loaded. I've also tried using Me.Controls instead of Userform1.Controls in the For Each statement with the same result.  Also, thanks for the suggestion to rename sum, I just couldn't pass up the Dim sum word play :)

Comment: When you say "Userform", do you mean a regular Access form? Userforms are what you use e.g. in Excel VBA, Access forms are different. -- If this code runs in the form module, then definitely use `Me.Controls`. -- Try a `Debug.Print Me.Controls.Count` before the `For Each`.

Comment: No, I mean a userform, as in the kind of form someone would create in Excel if they decided that the sheet needed a form. This was supposed to be a temporary solution and didn't warrant the creation of an Access form. -- Debug.Print shows that I have 8 controls, which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
Dim ctl As CheckBox
```

Answer (score 0):

*I am guessing here, but is your error on `If ctl.Value = True Then sum = sum + ctl.Tag`? The value you are likely looking for is `-1` not `True` as that is how check boxes evaluate in Access-VBA.*

**Edit:**

Whoops, ignore that. I think I see the problem, change `For Each ctl In Userform1.Controls` to `For Each ctl In Forms(Userform1).Controls`

Comment: Good catch on the -1 value instead of True. Just for posterity, the debugger wasn't getting that far into the code. It's hanging on the For Each statement.

Comment: As for your answer in the edited section, I made the change and it's still giving a mismatch error and it's still saying that ctl = Nothing.

Comment: Two things I can think of to check the form in question is literally called "Userform1". And second, I guess what Access version you might be using.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely Userform1. I even changed the name to "Bob" and changed the code to "Forms(Bob).Controls" to make sure that the names match. No fix.  I'm using Access 2013. The weird thing is that I have an Access form that uses a similar For Each  statement like it's going out of style and none of the loops give me this problem. The only thing I can think of is it's different for userforms somehow, which doesn't make sense to me.